# Integration by Residue Theorem - Is This Integral equal to Zero?

Tags: improper-integrals, residue-calculus

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{2x^{5}-3jx^{3}+2x}dx=0
$$

$$(1)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{2x^{5}-3jx^{3}+2x}dx=\frac{1}{2j}(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{jx}}{2x^{5}-3jx^{3}+2x}dx-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-jx}}{2x^{5}-3jx^{3}+2x}dx)
$$

Singularities:

$z_0=0\,,\, z_1= 1+j\,,\,z_2=-1-j\,,\,z_3 = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}j\,,\,z_4 = -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}j$

They are all simple poles.

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{jz}}{2z^{5}-3jz^{3}+2z}$$
$$g(z)=\frac{e^{-jz}}{2z^{5}-3jz^{3}+2z}$$

Residues of $f(z)$ e $g(z)$:
$$Res_f[0]=Res_g[0]=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$Res_f[1+j]=Res_g[-1-j]=\frac{e^{-1+j}}{-20}$$
$$Res_f[-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}j]=Res_g[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}j]=\frac{-e^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}j}}{5}$$

Therefore,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{2x^{5}-3jx^{3}+2x}dx=\frac{1}{2j}2\Pi j[0]=0$$

Edit:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{2x^{5}-3jx^{3}+2x}dx=\Pi(1+\frac{e^{-1+j}}{10}-\frac{2e^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}j}}{5})$$

Right?

Comment: Note that one of the closed contours is traversed in clockwise direction, the residues in the lower half-plane thus contribute their $-2\pi i$-fold to the integral.

Comment: is It now correct?

Comment: I'm off to dinner now, will check it after that.

Comment: The Maple code $$int(sin(x)/(2*x^5-(3*I)*x^3+2*x), x = -infinity .. infinity, numeric) $$ produces $ 0.8394684189+ 0.2681617236\,i $ and $$int(sin(x)/(2*x^5-(3*I)*x^3+2*x), x = -infinity .. infinity) $$ outputs $$-2/5\,\pi \,\cos \left( 1/2-1/2\,i \right) -1/10\,\pi \,\cos \left( 1+
i \right) +2/5\,i\pi \,\sin \left( 1/2-1/2\,i \right) -1/10\,i\pi \,
\sin \left( 1+i \right) +1/2\,\pi .
 $$

Comment: I think you have a sign error, and the residues at $0$ only count half, since they are on the contour, it should be $$\pi\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{e^{-1+j}}{10} - \frac{2e^{-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}j}}{5} \right),$$ if I didn't miscompute.